# Pivot functionwith multiple conditions (concatenated in one header)

Tags: sql-server

I have this query written in Microsoft Access, but I need to convert it to run on SQL Server.  I read multiple answers on dynamic pivoting in SQL Server, but can not apply it to my particular code, since I don't know how to pivot multiple conditions that are concatenated in one header.

Here is the code in Access:

```
TRANSFORM SUM(Sales.Tons) AS SumOfTons
SELECT     Sales.ID_SaleDest 
FROM       (QualPack 
INNER JOIN (Groups 
INNER JOIN (Customers 
INNER JOIN SaleDest 
ON         Customers.ID_Customer = SaleDest.ID_Customer) 
ON         Groups.ID_Group = SaleDest.ID_Group) 
ON         QualPack.ID_QualPack = SaleDest.ID_QualPack) 
INNER JOIN Sales 
ON         SaleDest.ID_SaleDest = Sales.ID_SaleDest 
WHERE      ((( 
                                            Year([Date_shipped]))=2017) 
           AND        (( 
                                            SaleDest.ID_Group)<>10) 
           AND        (( 
                                            QualPack.Quality_Second)<>'NO') 
           AND        (( 
                                            Sales.ID_Dataset)="AC" 
                      OR         ( 
                                            Sales.ID_Dataset)="BU")) 
OR         ((( 
                                            Year([Date_shipped]))=2016) 
           AND        (( 
                                            SaleDest.ID_Group)<>10) 
           AND        (( 
                                            QualPack.Quality_Second)<>'NO') 
           AND        (( 
                                            Sales.ID_Dataset)='AC')) 
GROUP BY   Sales.ID_SaleDest, 
           SaleDest.ID_Group 
ORDER BY   Sales.ID_SaleDest, 
           [Sales]![ID_Dataset] & '-' & Year([Sales]![Date_shipped]) & '-M' & Format(Month([Sales]![Date_shipped]),'00') 
PIVOT [Sales]![ID_Dataset] & '-' & YEAR([Sales]![Date_shipped]) & '-M' & Format(MONTH([Sales]![Date_shipped]),'00') 
WITH OWNERACCESS OPTION;
```

The problem is this:

```
PIVOT [Sales]![ID_Dataset] & '-' & YEAR([Sales]![Date_shipped]) & '-M' 
    & Format(MONTH([Sales]![Date_shipped]),'00')
```

How can I pivot this in mssql?

Idea is to summarize Tons for a particular SaleDest, by using Dataset, Year of Date_shipped and Month od date_shipped, but in one header (concatenated). For example, output for AC Dataset, Year 2017 and Month 1:

```
SaleDest    AC-2017-M01
2311        29,4
2313        2,8
2314        49,56
2320        24
```

Comment: Please have a look at this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196391/110455 , maybe you can get it using a GROUP BY solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Sales(SaleDest int, Tons decimal(18,2), DateShipped datetime, DataSet char(2));
> INSERT INTO Sales VALUES
> (2311, 20.4,  '20170401', 'AC'),
> (2311, 9,     '20170402', 'AC'),
> (2313, 1.4,   '20170405', 'AC'),
> (2313, 1.4,   '20170501', 'BU'),
> (2314, 29.56, '20170401', 'AC'),
> (2314, 20.0,  '20170505', 'BU'),
> (2320, 12,    '20170404', 'BU'),
> (2320, 12,    '20170505', 'BU');
> GO
> ```

I'd suggest you to use a temp table or a table variable to store the data source for the pivot solution.

I've simulated it in this way:

> ```
> SELECT SaleDest, 
>        Tons, 
>        DataSet 
>        + '-' + CAST(YEAR([Sales].[DateShipped]) AS varchar(4)) 
>        + '-M' + Format(MONTH([Sales].[DateShipped]),'00') as Caption
> FROM   Sales;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> SaleDest | Tons  | Caption    
> -------: | :---- | :----------
>     2311 | 20.40 | AC-2017-M04
>     2311 | 9.00  | AC-2017-M04
>     2313 | 1.40  | AC-2017-M04
>     2313 | 1.40  | BU-2017-M05
>     2314 | 29.56 | AC-2017-M04
>     2314 | 20.00 | BU-2017-M05
>     2320 | 12.00 | BU-2017-M04
>     2320 | 12.00 | BU-2017-M05
> ```

Now you should build columns names:

> ```
> DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max);
>
> SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' 
>                                    + QUOTENAME(DataSet 
>                                    + '-' 
>                                    + CAST(YEAR([Sales].[DateShipped]) AS varchar(4)) 
>                                    + '-M' 
>                                    + Format(MONTH([Sales].[DateShipped]),'00'))
>                    FROM Sales
>                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
>                   ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');
>
> SELECT @cols;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name)                          |
> | :---------------------------------------- |
> | [AC-2017-M04],[BU-2017-M04],[BU-2017-M05] |
> ```

And finally the dynamic pivot query:

> ```
> DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max);
>
> SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' 
>                                    + QUOTENAME(DataSet 
>                                    + '-' 
>                                    + CAST(YEAR([Sales].[DateShipped]) AS varchar(4)) 
>                                    + '-M' 
>                                    + Format(MONTH([Sales].[DateShipped]),'00'))
>                    FROM Sales
>                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
>                   ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');
>
> DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
>
> SET @CMD = 
> 'SELECT SaleDest, ' + @cols + ' FROM
> (
> SELECT SaleDest, 
>        Tons, 
>        DataSet 
>        + ''-'' + CAST(YEAR([Sales].[DateShipped]) AS varchar(4)) 
>        + ''-M'' + Format(MONTH([Sales].[DateShipped]),''00'') as Caption
> FROM   Sales) SRC
> PIVOT
> (
>     SUM(Tons) FOR Caption IN (' + @cols + ')
> ) PVT'
>
> EXEC(@cmd);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> SaleDest | AC-2017-M04 | BU-2017-M04 | BU-2017-M05
> -------: | :---------- | :---------- | :----------
>     2311 | 29.40       | null        | null       
>     2313 | 1.40        | null        | 1.40       
>     2314 | 29.56       | null        | 20.00      
>     2320 | null        | 12.00       | 12.00
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=371e50f744a8256a93f4972d08816023)*

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for your help. I applied it and it works :) You made my day!!

Comment: I am new to this site and I am not familiar with the process. I accepted and voted up for the answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: I'm glad to help.