# Query with CASE expressions on a Logger Devices database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, query

```
select t.DATETIME,  max(t.Depth) Depth,  max(t.Temperature) Temperature from(
                SELECT CAST(readingDTTM AS DATETIME) DATETIME, 
                case Sensor when 'Depth' then lValue end as Depth, 
                case Sensor when 'Temperature' then lValue end as Temperature
                FROM loggerData2 WHERE sName = 'Easington' AND 
                Sensor in ('Depth','Temperature')
                GROUP BY CAST(readingDTTM AS DATETIME), lValue, Sensor
   )t 
group by t.DATETIME ORDER BY t.DATETIME DESC;
```

The above query shows the following results when querying my database table called `loggerData2`.
It gets a distinct `DATETIME` based on both `Depth` and `Temperature` (`Sensor` in the database table).

```
DATETIME              Depth     Temperature
-------------------   ------    -----------     
09/10/2018 10:30:00   48.670    10.35   
09/10/2018 10:00:00   48.670    10.35   
09/10/2018 09:30:00   48.670    10.35   
09/10/2018 09:00:00   48.670    10.35   
09/10/2018 08:30:00   48.670    10.35   
09/10/2018 08:00:00   48.670    10.35   
09/10/2018 07:30:00   48.680    10.35   
09/10/2018 07:00:00   48.670    10.35   
09/10/2018 06:30:00   48.670    10.35
```

My problem now is this is only set up for one `site` at a time.

What I am trying to do is the same as the above query, but this time for only `Depth` (`sensor`) but for multiple `sites` (`sName`).

```
DATE TIME             Depth (sitename1)   Depth (sitename2)
-------------------   -----------------   -----------------
09/10/2018 10:30:00   48.670              46.756    
09/10/2018 10:00:00   48.670              46.756    
09/10/2018 09:30:00   48.670              46.756    
09/10/2018 09:00:00   48.670              46.756    
09/10/2018 08:30:00   48.670              46.756    
09/10/2018 08:00:00   48.670              46.756    
09/10/2018 07:30:00   48.680              46.756    
09/10/2018 07:00:00   48.670              46.756    
09/10/2018 06:30:00   48.670              46.756
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add `loggerData2` table schema. What columns define the sitename?

Comment: I am running this in vba - sorry about that.

Comment: I have changed sql query sorry about that

Comment: Is there a limited and well-known number of sitenames?

Comment: there are hundreds of sNames and normally they just choose which one to view data from.  now they want to be able to load all data from up to 20 sNames.  sNames are based on variables from the form they use ... thanks for your help on this

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196391/110455

Answer (score 3):

You can get it by using [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) relational operator, but it requires a dynamic query due you don't know the name of SiteName in advance.

The [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) query builds a coma-separated string with the names of the sites. The PIVOT query use its to get MAX(Depth) of each site.

```
DECLARE @col AS nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @cmd AS nvarchar(max);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(sName) 
                   FROM loggerData2
                   WHERE sName = sName IN ('SiteName1', 'SiteName2', ...)
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                   ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

SET @cmd =    'SELECT DT, ' + @col
            + 'FROM 
               (
                   SELECT 
                      sName as SiteName,
                      CAST(readingDTTM AS DATETIME) DT,
                      lValue as Depth
                   FROM 
                     loggerData2
                   WHERE 
                     sName = sName IN ('SiteName1', 'SiteName2', ...)
                     AND Sensor = 'Depth'
               ) src
               PIVOT
               (
                    MAX(Depth) FOR SiteName IN (' + @col + ')'
            + ') pvt';

EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;
```